# CannotPullContainerError: no space left on device AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I have a Docker container stored in Elastic Container Registry which has a size of 8393.29(MB) according to ECR. My issue is that whenever I create a task definition, then a service to finally launch the task to pull and run this container, the task remains in the pending status for some minutes and then stops with this message:

***CannotPullContainerError: ref pull has been retried 1 time(s): failed to extract layer sha256:8a8b75c9ef4bfdc6c33f2920198630f7a44669323d53bcb197b1c0269d7f0bfc: write /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/244/fs/text_models/src/topic_modeling/linkend_words/pytorch_weights.tar.gz: no space left on device: unknown***

I've searched around the internet and tried some things like incrementing the Task vCPU and Memory but have not found what exactly could be the issue here. Seems like there's no space left for that file called ***pytorch_weights.tar.gz***. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"No space left on device" is referring to disk volume space, not CPU or RAM. Try [increasing the ephemeral storage space](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/fargate-task-storage.html) allocated to your Fargate tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried to check the ephemeral storage before, but I am unable to see the option that allows me to increase it when configuring my task definition. Do you know if the option should show up? Or does it have to be done via CLI.

Comment: I've never used the UI to create a task definition. It is the `ephemeralStorage` property in the task definition JSON.

Comment: Alright I will try to create my task via CLI and increment that parameter. Thanks